# Are there standard visual cues or other methods for flaring in a B737-800?

Tags: landing, boeing-737, pilot-technique

Just a newbie in the 737. I've flown 100 hours - in real life - in this lovely beast and found the landing to be very confusing: my main problem is every time just from 50 feet, the sink feels too much. I don’t understand the right time to flare, almost every time it’s early or late. Also that I can’t flare at one go. Very very frustrating. Maybe a lot to do with seating position? Can you suggest the right visual cues or other techniques to use?

Comment: Are you talking about sim or real-life?

Comment: Real life brother

Comment: One thing that might help you is putting the arm rests at maximum height. This allows you to control the yoke more precisely, by resting your arms firmly on the arm rests.

Comment: Have a look at this by James Albright: https://code7700.com/landing_flare.htm

He suggests two things. 
1. A "scientific" flare ought to be possible, i.e. an ideal flare should take a certain number of seconds. I'm not sure what this number is in a B737. We are given a number for rotation: it should take approx 7 seconds. Here https://www.code7700.com/landing.htm he says a flare should take no more than 4 seconds.
2. Keep a landing diary! Describe your landings in writing, and you will find it easier to improve them.

Comment: In my airline, we are told to start to flare the 737 at 20 feet. With a descent rate of approx 10 feet per second, I start thinking about flaring at 25 feet, to give my brain half a second to get ready. The throttle should be closed smoothly, not suddenly.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but proceeding from what I think you may be asking, consider the following.

Are you flaring from a stabilized approach? Until a pilot internalizes things for any large aircraft, using a stabilized approach on speed appropriate to your landing weight gives a common, starting reference to work from.

From such an approach you should have been given in training the altitude from which to start the flare. For purposes of discussion, let's say that's the 50 feet you mentioned. Thus, the first problem is determining when you're at that point. Assuming you have a radar altimeter, are you using the call outs from the altimeter to consistently start the flare at the same altitude?

Now, in a stabilized approach, you don't feel a change in sink rate in the seat of your pants until you actually start the flare, so when you say "the sink feels too much", I'm assuming that you're having trouble with the rate of your flare. In other words, how much back pressure you should be exerting on the yoke. My thought would be that you could try focusing on how much to raise the nose at the 50 foot call rather than trying for a given amount of feel in the seat of your pants. I never flew the 737, but on the 747, at the 50 foot call, I would would raise the nose to 5° higher than it was during the stabilized approach. Then at the 10 foot call, I would raise it 2° higher yet. There would, of course, be an appropriate power reduction each time.

The 737 will have different numbers than the 747, but what I'm suggesting is to try doing it by the numbers, consistently, every time. Any 737 instructor should be able to tell you what those numbers are. You might even try posting a question here asking specifically what those numbers are. Perhaps a 737 pilot will see this answer and provide them.

Finally, an advantage of doing things by the numbers is that it really doesn't matter what your seat position is, although you should certainly go for a seat position that will eventually allow you to best internalize what the numbers mean insofar as the view out the windshield. When I transitioned from the F-27 to the SA-227, I found the view out the front confusing, but no matter since they taught us to simply do it by the numbers at first.

My apologies if my answer has been too pedantic or if I have misunderstood the question. If so, let me know in a comment and I'll be happy to delete the answer.

Comment: Sir, at first take my greetings. Wish I had met such a humble person in real life. Yes sir my problem is how much to pull confusion. Even if I come with a beautiful approach in calm wind, when I shift my view to the tress on the end of the runway, I feel like I am falling fast. And things get rough. Sometimes I try flaring at 30, 20 ; and then cut power at 10. Works and sometimes doesn’t. If only I could take a reference.  Thanks again Sir.

Comment: And sir that you mentioned about pitching up 5 degrees. Sir do you look at instruments and pitch up?

Comment: @AsifNizam Do you really need to "shift my view to the tress on the end of the runway."  If you're on the glidepath and aligned with the runway, you know you're not going to hit the trees, so why look directly at them. My thought would be that it's better to be looking at the VASI/PAPI and the runway touchdown zone and then down the runway. Just a thought.

Comment: @AsifNizam Yes, we did use the artificial horizon for pitch attitude in the flare to get the initial 5 degrees nose up increase. Some would say you shouldn't have your eyes in the cockpit at all during the flare, but it worked for us. In the 747, though, it was easy as it came down the glideslope at 5 degrees up, so adding another 5 put it at 10 degrees and there was a 10 degrees mark on artificial horizon. That made it easy to see with a quick glance. The additional 2 degrees at the 10 foot call we mostly did with just a bit more yoke movement. – Terry 8 mins ago

Comment: Thanks a ton Sir. I hope I can scan the attitude indicator this time. Will sure let u know if this works. :)